# Не()доеденный ребенком обед

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Не()доеденный ребенком обед - слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

***Не доеденный ребёнком обед***

Причастие от глагола "доесть". Есть зависимое слово ребёнком - пишем НЕ отдельно. Ср.: *недоеденный обед* - нет зависимого слова, нет противопоставления.

Не путать написание  причастия с правописанием глаголов *недоесть* и *не доесть*.

*недоесть*
недо'есть, -'ем, -'ешь, -'ест, -ед'им, -ед'ите, -ед'ят; прош. вр. -'ел, -'ела (*поесть не досыта*), но: *не до'есть* (*ещё не до'ел втор'ого*)

*Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.*